# Tuning a SQL server query by creating a new table however executing it takes a lot of time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to run this query in SQL server but ran into problem, it takes a lot of time to get executed, I want to know is it the correct way to create a table there are many records and it stops working so basically I want to create a table with index and insert these record into the new table and set the job to read the record from that table.

This is the old query that takes a lot of time time to be executed

```
 Update UsedTrs set Deleted=b.Deleted from
 UsedTrs a inner join UsedTrs_Live b
 on(a.ItemID=b.ItemID)
 where (a.ArabicDate=b.ArabicDate collate Arabic_CI_AS) and (a.Deleted!=b.Deleted) and
 (a.Code=b.Code) and (a.ItemType=b.ItemType) and 
 (a.ArabicDate>dbo.WesternToArabic(GETDATE()-90))
```

This is the new way that I have tried to insert it into a new table, but that takes a lot of time as well, my colleague said that collate Arabic_CI_AS will decrease the performance in the join which is on my first code, so I have tried this way to insert everything in a new table table and put indexes on the table and then grab the information through out the new table

here is the query for the new table but that takes a lot of time i am not sure if i am doing it correctly

```
select [id]
  ,[CreateDate]
  ,[TrsUserID]
  ,[UsedAmount]
  ,[ItemID]
  ,[ItemType]
  ,[Code]
  ,[Deleted]
  ,[ArabicDate]collate Arabic_CI_AS as [ArabicDate]
  ,[CostTypeFlag]
  Into UsedTrs_Live_use_for_sp_TrsAmounts
  From TrsUsed_Live 
  Where ArabicDate> dbo.WesternToArabic(GETDATE()-5)
```

update: it is now an hour already to run the query and it still executing and doesn't show any sign of completing, normally it should be faster, i don't know if that is the correct way

here is WesternToArabic function

```
      SET ANSI_NULLS ON
       GO
      SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
                GO
                ALTER    FUNCTION [dbo].[WesternToArabic](@indate 
                   DATETIME) RETURNS CHAR(10)
                    AS
                     BEGIN
                      DECLARE
                       @OutDate CHAR(10),
                       @DD     NUMERIC, 
                       @S        INT, 
                       @M       INT, 
                       @R       INT, 
                       @TMP  VARCHAR(10), 
                       @tmp1  NUMERIC, 
                       @tmp2  NUMERIC

                       SET @tmp1 = CONVERT(NUMERIC, DATEADD(yy, 200, DATEADD(hh, -12, 
                    @indate)))
                       SET @tmp2 = CONVERT(NUMERIC, CAST('18360320' AS DATETIME))
                       SET @DD = @tmp1- @tmp2
                       SET @S = ( FLOOR(@DD/46751)) * 128  +  1015
                       SET @DD =  @Dd - FLOOR(@DD/ 46751) * 46751
                       SET @S = ( FLOOR(@DD/12053)) * 33  + @S
                       SET @DD =  @DD - FLOOR(@Dd/12053) * 12053
                       IF @DD > 1826 
                       BEGIN
                          SET @DD = @DD - 1826
                          SET @S  = @S  +  5  +  FLOOR(@DD /1461) * 4
                          SET @DD = @Dd - FLOOR(@Dd/1461) * 1461
                       END
                       IF @DD > 365
                       BEGIN
                          SET @DD = @DD - 1
                          SET @S = @S  +  FLOOR(@DD / 365)
                          SET @DD =  @Dd - FLOOR(@DD/365) * 365
                       END
                       IF @DD > 185
                       BEGIN
                          SET @DD = @DD - 186
                          SET @R = @Dd - FLOOR(@DD/30) * 30  +  1
                          SET @M = FLOOR(@DD/30)  + 7
                       END
                       ELSE
                       BEGIN
                          SET @R = @Dd - FLOOR(@DD/31) * 31  +  1
                          SET @M = FLOOR(@DD/31)  + 1;
                       END
                       IF @M < 10
                          SET @tmp = CAST(@S AS CHAR(4)) + '/0' + CAST(@M AS CHAR(1))
                       ELSE
                          SET @tmp = CAST(@S AS CHAR(4)) + '/' + CAST(@M AS CHAR(2))
                       IF @R < 10
                          SET @outdate = @tmp + '/0'  + CAST(@R AS CHAR(1))
                       ELSE
                          SET @outdate = @tmp + '/'  + CAST(@R AS CHAR(2))

                       RETURN(@OutDate)

                    END
```

Comment: I guess your sql server hosted in a slow server

Comment: `dbo.WesternToArabic` is quite likely the major culprit here, if it's a scalar-valued function. Prior to SQL Server 2019 these invariably had horrendous performance as they suppress parallelism and force row-by-row evaluation. SQL Server 2019 improves things a bit with the ability to inline these functions, but that feature is buggy and also has lots of exceptions that prevent a function from being inlined. Consider rewriting `dbo.WesternToArabic` so it's a table-valued function you can `CROSS APPLY` instead (or create a new function for that purpose).

Comment: Note that if you do rewrite your function  `dbo.WesternToArabic` to a table value function, make sure it's an **inline** table value function. Multi-line table value functions also more than often perform very poorly too.

Comment: It's a scalar valued function,  I tried CROSS APPLY but I was unable to find the function dbo.ArabicToWestern function,  how can I rewrite it in a way that has better performance,     When in where clause a big part of a table with using Id we insert it in a new table it works, but when I use dbo.WesternToArabic in a new table takes a lot of time

Comment: Can you share the definition of `dbo.WesternToArabic`?

Comment: i send it in a post since it was too long to type here

Comment: You can always [edit] your original question to supply more details; don't use answers for that.